# TypeScript: Creating offscreen canvas inside webworker

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, web-worker, offscreen-canvas

I have Angular project that has generated web-worker with attached canvas to it using `transferControlToOffscreen`. Everything went well until I needed to create another `OffscreenCanvas` inside the web-worker. Now the build is throwing `TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.`.

I believe it's something with `tsconfig` file but I can't for life figure out what it is exactly.

`tsconfig.worker.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/worker",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es7",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "src/custom_typings.d.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post some code too. I have never used 'filesGlob', you could try to exclude "src/**/*.worker.ts" there.

Comment: There's nothing to post really. I'm just creating a variable inside a worker on which I just assign a value of `new OffscreenCanvas(0, 0)`. That's it.

Comment: @SuperKeksmann what I found out is that if I slap a `@ts-ignore` on the line, where I use the `OffscreenCanvas` class - it works. Not only it builds - it creates the object. But I strongly feel like it's a hack

Comment: It seems like the compiler thinks the worker module is a standart ts-module, have you tried to exclude `"src/**/*.worker.ts"` in the default `tsconfig`?

Comment: @SuperKeksmann it's already excluded in `tsconfig.app.json`